# Bing API v1 documentation

Tags: c#, bing, bing-api

Does anyone know where I can find the latest documention for Bings API with the following URL:

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Web
```

Even their own website has the wrong URL in the word docs I have been reading, i.e. https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web does not work.

I can get the search to work and return results, but cannot get the total record count, if I use composite I can get record count but no results.

I just looking for an up-to-date example of how to get both count and results.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class GetBingTotalRecordCount
{
    public IEnumerable<DisplayBingWebSearch> DisplayBingSearchResults(string q)
    {
        string BingID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Bing_WebSearchID"];
        string BingWebSearch
            = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Bing_WebSearchURL"];
        var BingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(BingWebSearch));
        BingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(BingID, BingID);
        var query = BingContainer.Composite("Web", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(q),
            "EnableHighlighting", "DisableQueryAlterations", "en-GB", "Strict",
            null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
        ).Execute().First();

        List<DisplayBingWebSearch> data = new List<DisplayBingWebSearch>();
        foreach (var results in query.Web)
        {
            data.Add(new DisplayBingWebSearch() {
                 WebTitle = results.Title
            });
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform your own counts and paging.

results.Count from your foreach statement would get the number of records returned.

There is a maximum of 50 results per query and you can specify the maximum result count with 
$top=x where x is your desired  maximum result.

Ex: `https://user:yourAccountKey@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27leo%20fender%27&Market=%27en-US%27&$top=50&$format=JSON"`

Bing uses OData parameters in the queries now so $top would be the number of results to return and $skip is the offset.

The FAQ with examples of $top and $skip can be found at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252146

The migration guide, which is not very helpful, can be found here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248077