# How to get more than 50 results from Bing search API v1?

Tags: php, bing, bing-api

I have used the code below with the Bing image API to search images.  But the code gets only 50 results.  How can I get more results?

```
$acctKey = 'Account key here';
$rootUri = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search';
$query = 'Kitchen';
$serviceOp = 'Image';
$market ='en-us';
$query = urlencode("'$query'");
$market = urlencode("'$market'");
$requestUri = "$rootUri/$serviceOp?\$format=json&Query=$query&Market=$market";
$auth = base64_encode("$acctKey:$acctKey");
$data = array(  
            'http' => array(
                        'request_fulluri' => true,
                        'ignore_errors' => true,
                        'header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"
                        )
            );
$context = stream_context_create($data);
$response = file_get_contents($requestUri, 0, $context);
$response=json_decode($response);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bing API v1 documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244280/bing-api-v1-documentation)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but it explains that you can only get 50 results per query, but you can use the `skip` parameter to specify where to start (so you can make multiple queries to build up a larger result set)

Comment: when i have use the skip parameter like $requestUri.="&$skip=50" it is return empty results

Comment: you have to include all the other parameters...

Comment: the same happens for Bing v7, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76097614/how-to-get-more-than-100-results-with-the-bing-search-api-v7/76097615

Answer (score 2):

You should append your request with $top=50&$skip=0 to get the first 50 results and with $top=50&$skip=51 to get the next 50 results, it's better to create API key to get the second request as Bing permits 1 transaction per second and you may get this message error if you exceeded the limits: "503 The number
 of requests per minute for the subscription has reached the maximum threshold that is allowed."